# Class not found server client Java

Tags: classnotfound

I know that this question has been asked many times but any of the answers help me to get ride of the problem.
I am working on a IM program  using Java (netbeans)...

I have a class called **"message"** in the client side,  and I pass the class from client to server, and in the *server* there is a class called **messege** similar to **messege** class on the *client* side.

I uses ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream to send/receive the Class from/to the server,
and the **server** program tell: ClassNotFound exception and point to message class that exist in the **client** side.

how to solve this problem.

***points:***
 - the Class Message exist on the two sides, and not missed!
 - I passes an object not a class
 - the classes are Serializable
 - I used casting :

```
msg= (message) SomeObjectInputStream.ReadObject();
```

---

Here is the exact error messages :

> Oct 05, 2013 4:32:40 PM EIQserver.EIQserver run
>   SEVERE: null

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RandomSend.Message
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at EIQserver.EIQserver.run(EIQserver.java:55)
```

My class:

public class Message implements Serializable {...}

and the error is pointing here:

```
  fromuser=(Message) OIS.readObject();
```

***Important: I also Defined the class in the same file of the client class and in the server class (instead of separated files), but still get the same Exception!!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:
1)Dont define the Class in the two sides )cliet & server, Just define a class on the Client.
2)Import the class in the server side

```
import clientSide.Message;
```

and that's is

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in your code. "message" on the client and "massege" on the server.

Comment: no, the typo just here in the post, in my code the same name exactly